# alter function to count vbRed

Tags: excel, vba, function, count

I've been trying to alter the function below to count vbRed instead of any color defined by 'criteria':

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Variations such as the one below fail:

```
Function CountRed(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range    

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
        CountRed= CountRed+ 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your variation to work, remove `DisplayFormat`.

For example (this is your code with `DisplayFormat` removed):

```
Function CountRed(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            CountRed = CountRed + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```